# Directshow EVR slow video playback

Tags: video, directshow, video-processing, ms-media-foundation

I have coded a video player using directshow and EVR filter. I am having a problem of slow playback in a machine with configuration:

Processor: AMD E-350 1.60 GHz
Ram: 2 GB

The videos with resolution 1440*1080 or 1920*1080 and above plays fine in windows media player and Media player classic-HC but not the way I am rendering it.

PLayback is smooth in other machines with processors like intel dual core and above.

I am just adding the evr filter to the graph i have made of the video and playing it.
Is there any way to improve the playback quality of the video on this machine.
any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth it to investigate the FPU in that system.  An inefficient FPU can really hurt the performance of a directshow module, especially if you are not using the GPU for heavy calculations.